# AppleScript for AirPlay Button in the new TV app

Tags: user-interface, applescript, television

Can anybody figure out how to click the AirPlay Display pop up button in the new TV app (found in MacOS Catalina) using AppleScript? I've tried a zillion different ways, and still get the result "missing value."

As far as I know this code *should* work:

```
    tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "TV"
        tell window 1
            click ((button whose description is "airplay") of pop up button 1)
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Here is a picture of the Accessibility Inspector for that pop up button:
[image: Accessibility Inspector]

UPDATE: Apparently the new TV app in Catalina is not fully scriptable. AppleScript support for AirPlay Displays does not exist (neither directly nor through GUI scripting). Hopefully, Apple will add support in the future...